# getting undefined reference to typeinfo for MemoryPool and all of my methods are defined

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, abstract-class, linker-errors

I know the usual cause for this message. However, I don't think that's happening here unless I'm missing something. I think the problem is cropping up because I'm deriving from an abstract base with a template class and it's not resolving all the methods because of that. The trouble is, I don't know how to fix it. I normally try not to mix templates and inheritance, but in this case I need fixed size array buffers and the only other way I know to accomplish this is to use the preprocessor rather than the compiler w/ templates. (Forgive any bugs in the code, I haven't even had a chance to test the proof of concept yet because it won't compile)

I get this error (clipped slightly):

```
In function `pool::MemoryPool::MemoryPool()':
MemoryPool.hpp:11: undefined reference to `vtable for pool::MemoryPool'
undefined reference to `typeinfo for pool::MemoryPool'
```

I've already tried every combination of constructors and destructors (virtual and non) in MemoryPool and StaticMemoryPool to no avail.

Any help?

Thanks in advance.

here's the code:

```
struct MemoryPool {
    virtual void* alloc(const size_t size)=0;
    virtual void freeAll()=0;
    virtual void* next();
    virtual size_t capacity()=0;
    virtual size_t used()=0;
};
template<size_t C> class StaticMemoryPool : public MemoryPool {
    uint8_t _heap[C];
    uint8_t *_next;
public:
    void* alloc(const size_t size) override {
        if(used()+size>=C)
            return nullptr;
        void* result = _next;
        _next+=size;
        return result;
    }
    void freeAll() override {
        _next = _heap;
    }
    void *next() override {
        return _next;
    }
    size_t capacity() override { return C; }
    size_t used() override {return _next-_heap;}
    StaticMemoryPool() : _next(_heap) {}
    ~StaticMemoryPool() {}
};
```

Comment: In terms of the [Linux C++ ABI](https://refspecs.linuxbase.org/cxxabi-1.83.html#vague), `MemoryPool::next` is a key function. The key function specifies where the vtable and the typeinfo live. Therefore, the key function must be defined, and the vtable+typeinfo must be visible from the point of use (e.g. if separated by a shared library boundary).

Comment: `MemoryPool::next` is neither implemented nor made pure virtual.

Comment: OMG I've been at this all morning because I forgot an =0!

Comment: Here's a reproducer to play around with: https://godbolt.org/z/TofM16

Answer (score 1):

> MemoryPool::next is neither implemented nor made abstract.

– Igor Tandetnik

Thank you! You don't know how long I've been staring at that code looking for the problem!